# What do we mean hibernate session is not thread safe and should close as soon as possible

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, thread-safety

I am new to hibernate and I did not understand why we say that we should close session as soon as possible. Also how we care if it is a thread safe or not when each thread have a different session, Does the context say that should we share session between thread, which i don't think who would be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the session means releasing JDBC connection.so if we don't close the session ,we are not releasing the JDBC Connection,so as per the sizeof connection pool JDBC Connection will be establised and beyond that all the request will be in waiting state,since none of JDBC connection are free.